# How do I get the time email received time using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

Tags: c#, datetime, outlook, outlook-api

Newbie here, need to get a DateTime value for when each email was originally received.

EDIT: Added code. I have the item, I am just trying to get the time received but I cannot find the property for it.

```
            foreach (MailItem item in mailItems)
            {
                emailDetails = new OutlookEmails
                {
                    EmailFrom = item.SenderEmailAddress,
                    EmailSubject = item.Subject,
                    EmailBody = item.Body

                };
                listEmailDetails.Add(emailDetails);
                ReleaseComObject(item);
            }
```

Comment: According the the MS documentation, each MailItem has a ReceivedTime on it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.receivedtime?view=outlook-pia

Comment: Do you just need help identifying the right MAPI property, or do you need help reading it? Do you already have the IMailItem?

Comment: Hey, added a snippet of code where I am trying to get the received time. I have the item, I just can't figure out how to get the received time from it

Comment: item.receivedTime is the answer! Cheers guys

Answer (score 1):

item.ReceivedTime is the answer.

Credit to: 
[user1011627](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011627/user1011627)